# Self-test fails with python error 'global name 'parser' is not defined'

Tags: sonos

Im running the self-test and in doing so i am getting several failures with the instance message: "global name 'parser' is not defined"

I have all packages installed for python (using version 2.7 on Ubuntu ) and its only the tests for the updateTestContent part of the suite that fails.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to fix this error?

An example of the output is: (but im getting this exact same error about 30 times on the UpdateTestContent tests)

> Stopped    UpdateTestContent test_combinatorial_get_test_content_173616823212099076936397683973588533375   (mediaCollection){ id = "top" itemType = "container" displayType = "list" title = "HitsNL top30" canPlay = True canEnumerate = True albumArtURI = "https://external.unplug.de/img/hitsnl_top_30.png" }
>
> Instance Messages:
>   `global name 'parser' is not defined`
>
> 2016-06-27 16:42:08,503 [INFO] SONOS.sonos.workflow.fixture.UpdateTestContent - Test Case: 1 UpdateTestContent test_combinatorial_get_test_content_173616823212099076936397683973588533375

```
(mediaCollection){
    id = "top"
    itemType = "container"
    displayType = "list"
    title = "HitsNL top30"
    canPlay = True
    canEnumerate = True
    albumArtURI = "https://external.unplug.de/img/hitsnl_top_30.png"
})
```

> 2016-06-27 16:42:08,503 [PASS] SONOS.sonos.workflow.fixture.UpdateTestContent - No test content needs updating. (expression is True)
>
> 2016-06-27 16:42:08,503 [STOP] SONOS.sonos.workflow.fixture.UpdateTestContent - global name 'parser' is not defined
>
> 2016-06-27 16:42:08,503 [STOP] SONOS.sonos.workflow.fixture.UpdateTestContent - 1 UpdateTestContent test_combinatorial_get_test_content_173616823212099076936397683973588533375
>
> 2016-06-27 16:42:08,504 [DEBUG] SONOS.sonos.workflow.fixture.UpdateTestContent - [('../../sonos-1.1.0.dev_r248336-py2.7.egg/sonos/workflow/fixture.py', 2483, '_run_test_iteration', 'testMethod(factoryTestValues)'), ('/home/zazell/Applications/sonos/smapi/content_workflow/updatetestcontent.py', 90, 'test_combinatorial_get_test_content', 'self.smapiservice.**init**(self.smapiservice.configfile, parser.wsdl, CRAWLER_DISABLE)')]
>
> 2016-06-27 16:42:08,504 [INFO] SONOS.sonos.workflow.fixture.UpdateTestContent - -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -
>
> 2016-06-27 16:42:08,505 [INFO] SONOS.sonos.workflow.result - End *test iteration* 0 of test case test_combinatorial_get_test_content at Monday, June 27, 2016 04:42 PM

Answer (score 0):

I finally managed to resolve this issue by adding 
`global parser
parser = ServiceConfigOptionParser(sys.argv)` 
to the **init** method of the UpdateTestContent class which makes it run properly.